# Using TCP keepalive for terminating orphan postgres queries not working

Tags: postgresql, tcp, keep-alive

**Problem**: A user of some application executes a report which involves a heavy sql query.  After some minutes, the user then quits the application (or even worse, the app crashes, or the connection to the database server is lost). The query however continues its execution, *even when it is no more needed*.

So I've read about these types of situations and how to handle them, and it is suggested to use [TCP Keepalive configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html).

The problem is that it looks like postgres is ignoring this configuration.  I've lowered the original configuration values both at "postgres level" and at "OS level", with no luck:

- **postgresql.conf**

  - tcp_keepalives_idle = 60
  - tcp_keepalives_interval = 6
  - tcp_keepalives_count = 10
- **Ubuntu**

  - echo 60 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
  - echo 10 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
  - echo 6 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probe

I even tried reloading/restarting postgres but nothing worked, the query keeps running past two minutes until the very end.  ¿Is there any additional step I am missing?

Comment: `The query however continues its execution, even when it is no more needed.` No, it doesn't. It is probably rolling back/recovering/cleaning up.

Comment: @joop roll back a Read Only query? I doubt cancelling the query request takes so long.  Besides, there is no change in the load average of the system, the query keeps performing for what I can tell.